# Accessing elements in dom which loads after window.load

Tags: jquery, pageload

How do I access elements in a HTML page which get loaded after `window.load` & `document.ready` functions?

I cannot access them using jQuery document ready or load.

Comment: explain with example..If its possible please create a fiddle

Comment: are you talking about accessing the dynamic HTML elements through JS ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you already mentioned jQuery, I'll give you a jQuery specific answer:

```
$("body").on("click",".selector-late",function(e){
    //Your Code Here.
    //e.delegateTarget returns the body element.
    //e.currentTarget returns .selector-late element.
    //e.target returns the element which was clicked. (could be a child of .selector-late too)
});
```

Explanation:

1. We are attaching the event listener on a element which is already existing. (`body` in this case, it could be any parent of the element.)
2. `click` is the event I've attached on. You can change according to requirement.
3. `.selector-late` will be the selector for your element that might load anytime in the future.

Signature

```
$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

This method is explained in [detail here.](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)

Answer (score 1):

If there's any event you can use when you need to access them, or when they arrive, use that event.

If there's no event you can hook into, you can wait for them to appear using a timer loop (e.g., polling for them):

```
(function() {
    function doSomething() {
        var elements = $("selector-for-the-elements");
        if (!elements.length) {
            // Not there yet, keep waiting
            setTimeout(doSomething, 100); // 100ms = 1/10th second, adjust as needed
            return;
        }
        // We have them, use them
    }
    $(doSomething); // Make the first call happen on document ready
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a trigger to access the element, the following will work:

```
$("<trigger>").on("click", function() {
  <access loaded element>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(".parent_class").on("click",".the_element_you_need",function() {
 //code here
});
```

Comment: Is there a load event ? Click event is not there in the page

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click",".your_element",function() {
 //do something
});
```